# Python creating dynamic YAML file using jinja2 for nested structures

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2, ruamel.yaml

I need to create a YAML file that is based on simple YAML that needs to be updated based on properties supplied by developers and contain the following YAML structure:

```yaml
- switch: null
  title: switch
  case:
    - condition: (parameter1==='Parameter1_value1')
      execute:
        - switch:
            case:
              - condition: $(parameter2) == "Parameter2_value1"
                execute:
                  - invoke:
                      parameter3:
                        parameter3_value1: null
              - condition: $(parameter2) == "Parameter2_value2"
                execute:
                  - invoke:
                      parameter3:
                        parameter3_value2: null
    - condition: (parameter1==='Parameter1_value2')
      execute:
        - switch:
            case:
              - condition: $(parameter2) == "Parameter2_value1"
                execute:
                  - invoke:
                      parameter3:
                        parameter3_value1: null
              - condition: $(parameter2) == "Parameter2_value2"
                execute:
                  - invoke:
                      parameter3:
                        parameter3_value2: null
```

Both `parameter1` and `parameter2` can have multiple values, so I need to populate the structure dynamically, according to the values that I receive.

I tried to do the following:

1. Import the following

```
import ruamel.yaml
from jinja2 import Template
```

2. Load the basic file -

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data_src = yaml.load(file_name)
```

In parallel receive the values from another JSON file, and once I have the data, I created using Jinja the following:

```
parameter2_data_tmpl = Template(""" -  condition: $(parameter2) == "{{ parameter2_value }}"
                        execute:
                          - invoke:
                              parameter3: {{ parameter3_value }}
                              
            """);
           
parameter2_data = parameter2_data_tmpl.render(parameter2_value = parameter2_value, parameter3_value = parameter3_value)
```

This works like a charm, and when I print it - it looks great. but then I tried to add the new YAML piece to the structure I have by first add it to relevant array (Using the append method), and then assign the array to the relevant element in the original YAML structure.

But when I add it to the array, it added it in different format:

```
case: [' -  condition: parameter2 == \"\
          parameter2_value\"\\n                        execute:\\n                          -\
                                        parameter3: parameter3_value\\n     \
```

It's like jinja2 created it correctly, but not as YAML syntax.

Why doesn't this work? Is there an alternative to creating these code dynamically?

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you're trying to do here. The indentation of your templates makes the hard to read, but I'm not even sure they're necessary. It looks like you should just be creating the corresponding Python data structures, and then calling `ruamel.yaml.dump` if you need YAML output.

Comment: Basically I am having a YAML template, and need to populate some of its element with arrays that will be generated from external file, when the arrays are not in a fixed size. so - for each element I generate- I am using jinja2 to create it as YAML element, and then I am trying to add it to the relevant Python array.  
But I will try to use the dump and load to see if I can "convert" the jinja2 result to YAML structure

Comment: @EyalGoren If you have a question involving ruamel.yaml, add the tag [tag:ruamel.yaml], That way people subscribing to that tag get notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the render is a string:

```py
from jinja2 import Template

parameter2_data_tmpl = Template(""" -  condition: $(parameter2) == "{{ parameter2_value }}"
                        execute:
                          - invoke:
                              parameter3: {{ parameter3_value }}
                              
            """);

parameter2_value = 'parameter2_value'
parameter3_value = 'parameter3_value'
parameter2_data = parameter2_data_tmpl.render(parameter2_value = parameter2_value, parameter3_value = parameter3_value)

print(type(parameter2_data))
```

This gives:

```
<class 'str'>
```

When you add that string somewhere in the datastructure that you loaded using `ruamel.yaml` you
get a quoted scalar.

What you want to do is add a **data structure**, but you cannot get from
the template, because the output of the render is not valid YAML.

You can directly create the data structure without rendering, if you don't want
to do that, you should change the template, so that it generates valid YAML input, load that
and then insert that data structure in the `data_src` at the appropriate place
(which is unclear from your incomplete program):

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from jinja2 import Template

parameter2_data_tmpl = Template("""\
-  condition: $(parameter2) == "{{ parameter2_value }}"
   execute:
     - invoke:
         parameter3: {{ parameter3_value }}
""");

parameter2_value = 'parameter2_value'
parameter3_value = 'parameter3_value'
parameter2_data = parameter2_data_tmpl.render(parameter2_value = parameter2_value, parameter3_value = parameter3_value)

    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
new_data = yaml.load(parameter2_data)

data = yaml.load("""\
case: some value to overwrite
""")
data['case'] = new_data
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
case:
  - condition: $(parameter2) == "parameter2_value"
    execute:
      - invoke:
          parameter3: parameter3_value
```

Please note that there also exists a plugin [`ruamel.yaml.jinja2`](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml.jinja2/)
that allows you to load
unrendered Jinja2 templates that generate YAML output and modify values.

Comment: Thanks Anthon, this seems to be working with one exception-
The original data structure is being indent differently from the new_data, is there a way to tell the ruamel to indent one section differently?
Because before I add it the the original structure-
data['case'] = new_data
I preform dump with a yaml that was configured with the relevant indent- and it works great, just when I add it to the original structure it allign the indentation with what exist there, and it cause problems

Comment: Hi Anthon, basically it works with one exception, the original yaml files contains one line that I don't change-
source: |2-

(I am not sure what the syntax means), but after changing the indentation as you wrote and dumping, in that line it changes-
source: |4-
Which makes it unvalid, any idea what can cause it?

Comment: That is because you have literal scalar (indicated by the |) that starts with a line that is indented, The nmber gives the number of indent of the body (i.e. the leftmost position of the left character). You can post a question with that particular line (you can change the words, but not the whitespace). I am on holiday so it might take till easter that you get an answer though

Comment: Hi Anthon, I managed to resolve it by rewriting the section so it will be indent correctly , and remove the number. Thanks!!!